# Replace text using saltstack

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I will need your assistance on the following:

I would like to replace an IP address within a file, regex is matching, but the output is totally wrong.

```
test.sls

wsc_start_server:
  file.managed:
    - name: /tmp/modify.txt
    - source: salt://modify.txt

{% set ip = grains['fqdn_ip4'] %}

wsc_jbos_replace_hostname:
  file.replace:
    - name: /tmp/modify.txt
    - pattern: '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'
    - repl: {{ ip }}
    - backup: '.bak'
    - show_changes: True



modify.txt

    address=y.y.y.y
    address.private=y.y.y.y



salt 'workstation' state.apply test.sls


output: 

address=['x.x.x.x']
address.private=['x.x.x.x']
```

When I am running the state why I am getting the ip address in ['x.x.x.x'] format instead of address=x.x.x.x ????

```
Note: y.y.y.y & x.x.x.x are IP Addresses
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the fqdn represent a list.

to fix the issue I change the following:

```
{% set ip = grains['fqdn_ip4'] %}

wsc_jbos_replace_hostname:
  file.replace:
    - name: /tmp/modify.txt
    - pattern: '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'
    - repl: {{ ip }}
    - backup: '.bak'
    - show_changes: True
```

to the correct one:

```
{% set ip = grains['fqdn_ip4'][0] %}

wsc_jbos_replace_hostname:
  file.replace:
    - name: /tmp/modify.txt
    - pattern: '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'
    - repl: {{ ip }}
    - backup: '.bak'
    - show_changes: True
```

it worked. :) :)